# Private element error

Tags: c++, private

### Class 1:

```
class Class1{
public:
    Class1(Class2 * a, int b );
    ~Class1();
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& x, const Class1& c1);

private:
    int b;
    Class2 * a;
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& x, const Class1& c1)
{
    stream<<"("<<c1.a->label<<","<<c1.b<<")"<<endl;
    return x;
}
```

### Class2 (In another file):

```
class Class2
{
public : 
   Class2 (string label);
   ~Class2();
  string getLabel()
  {
     return label; 
  }

private:
    string label;
    vector<Class1 *> c1vector;
};
```

### Question:

I'm trying to print the label and b of an edge, but it says the label is private. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Here's a good little read: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/friendship-not-inherited-transitive.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are trying to access a private member of Class2 directly, and the private property is actually what prevents you from doing this. (And the fact that you qualified `operator<<` friend in Class1 doesn't change anything, `label` is a private member of Class2).

Either make the member public (not recommended) or provide a public member function that returns the value of this member.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write in Class2 `friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& x, const Class1& c1);`, because only Class 1 is its friends but label if a private attibute of class2

Answer (score 1):

`label` is private within `Class2` so it cannot be access through `Class` or your `operator<<` insertion function. The simplest solution is to provide a public const `get_label` function in `Class2` to access the label string.

A more in depth approach is to give `Class2` its own print mechanism (either through a print/display/show function, or with its own `operator<<` that can be used to show the label.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that: `label` is private in `Class2`, you cannot directly access it inside `Class1` via an instance of `Class2`, which is `a` in this case. You may need to provide `getters` inside `Class2`.

```
 class Class2
 {
  public : 
      string getLable()
      {
         return label; 
      }
  private:
     string label;
};//^^other members skipped for clearance purpose
```

Comment: actually I already have that getter, I didn't put it in there but I still have that error.

Comment: @bahittin OK. then there should be some other issues which result in the error. I will remove my answer once I am able to. Sorry for not being able to help.